# async in node js is not working

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying to run two different mongoose queries and display the result in same ejs page. I searched a lot and finally found the async method. How I tried this is below.

> js file

```
router.get('/CreateSurvey', function(req, res, next) {

async.parallel([
        function(callback) {
            QBank.find( function ( err, classes, count ){
                classes : classes  
            });
        },
       function(callback) {
            QBank.findOne({_id:"H001"},  function ( err, questions, count ){     
                questions : questions
            });
        }
    ], function(err) { 
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.render('CreateSurvey', QBank);
    });
```

});

But when I refresh '/CreateSurvey' page it does not render. I have already downloaded async module and required in my js file. **Where am I wrong?**

Comment: I don't find anything wrong in ASYNC.PARALLEL what i think the issue is in QBank why are you passing it in  res.render() ?

Comment: I was following work by some others. I think both 'classes' and 'questions' will be assigned in same name 'QBank'. See the final answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402781/nodejs-mongoose-render-two-models-from-collections

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, What is that `classes : classes` and `questions : questions` lines in your code? What are you trying to do?

The `callback` parameter of each `task` function (*the functions in array*) should be called inside the task to indicate completion of each task with *success* or *error*.

The optional main `callback` (the third function in your code), where you are doing the actual rendering, will be called only after all the `tasks` have completed.

In your code `callback` is not called inside the `task`. As a result the final *callback* is also never getting called. In fact, in your code only the first *task gets executed and nothing happens beyond that.

Read more about `async.parallel` in [*documentation*](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel)

Comment: There is a question bank in my survey system. When the user goes to 'Import questions', I want to display the question type (class) and when the user clicks the type, the questions inside that type must be displayed. So, to display this by javascript hide & show in the same ejs page I want to send find all and find one to same ejs page.

Comment: So what is that syntax you are using for `.find()` in `mongoose`? You are reading all the questions in your database in one call? You want to do that?

Comment: You need to also get your code syntax right. Please see @MukeshSharma's reply. I suggest you first read relevant documentation of `mongoose` and `async`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the code, you aren't calling `callback` corresponding to `async` call. Try the following:

```
router.get('/CreateSurvey', function(req, res, next) {
  async.parallel({
    classes: function(callback) {
      QBank.find(function(err, classes, count){
        callback(classes);
      });
    },
    questions: function(callback) {
      QBank.findOne({_id:"H001"},  function (err, questions, count ){     
        callback(questions);
      });
    }
  }, function(err, result) { 
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.render('CreateSurvey', result); // { classes : [c1, c2] , questions : [q1, q2] }
  });
});
```